# Access arguments only allow administer and user logged in

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

I am building a module and used the following code to define a route for a user account.

How do I set the access arguments to only allow administrators and the user himself?

```php
$items['user/%/extra-settings'] = [
  'title' => t('extra Settings'),
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  'access arguments' => ['administer access'],
];
```

Comment: To begin, you need to set a 'page callback' rather than 'access arguments'. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x

Comment: There is a very good example in Drupal core: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/7.x/modules/user/user.module?ref_type=heads#L1807

Comment: Since the route should be shown to the person who "owns" the user account, access arguments cannot be used alone. You need to set the access callback, which by default is `user_access`. (That is why access arguments are a permission array.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the access arguments alone, you cannot give access to user/%/extra-settings to administrator users and the user "owning" the user account.

You need to define your own access callback that checks who is accessing the route.

```php
$items['user/%/extra-settings'] = [
  'title' => t('extra Settings'),
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  'access callback' => 'mymodule_extra_settings_access',
  'access arguments' => [1],
];
```

```php
function mymodule_extra_settings_access($account) {
  global $user;

  if (user_access('administer users')) {
    // The route is accessed by an administrator user with
    // the permission to administer users.
  }
  elseif ($account->uid == $user->uid) {
    // The route is accessed by the user who "owns" the user account.
  }
}
```

The permission to check depends on which administrator user should access the route. The code I used is for the case the administrator user is a user who can administer users. In the case the administrator user who can access the route is the user #1, it is sufficient to replace `user_access('administer users')` with `$user->uid == 1`.